# Multi auth based on roles VS multi guards authentication

Tags: laravel-8

I am a beginner in Laravel. I saw a couple of information on the web regarding multi auth based on roles and multi guards authentication.

As a beginner, I would like to hear what is the advantage and disadvantage of these two and when to use each for a specific purpose or situation.

I would appreciate your answers/opinions regarding this matter.